# Python 2.7 and 3.3.2, why int('0.0') does not work?

Tags: python, string, integer, type-conversion

As the title says, in Python (I tried in 2.7 and 3.3.2), why `int('0.0')` does not work? It gives this error:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '0.0'
```

If you try `int('0')` or `int(eval('0.0'))` it works...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply because `0.0` is not a valid integer of base 10. While `0` is.

Read about `int()` [here.](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#int)

> int(x, base=10)
>
> Convert a number or string x to an integer, or return
>   0 if no arguments are given. If x is a number, it can be a plain
>   integer, a long integer, or a floating point number. If x is floating
>   point, the conversion truncates towards zero. If the argument is
>   outside the integer range, the function returns a long object instead.
>
> If x is not a number or if base is given, then x must be a string or
>   Unicode object representing an integer literal in radix base.
>   Optionally, the literal can be preceded by + or - (with no space in
>   between) and surrounded by whitespace. A base-n literal consists of
>   the digits 0 to n-1, with a to z (or A to Z) having values 10 to 35.
>   The default base is 10. The allowed values are 0 and 2-36. Base-2, -8,
>   and -16 literals can be optionally prefixed with 0b/0B, 0o/0O/0, or
>   0x/0X, as with integer literals in code. Base 0 means to interpret the
>   string exactly as an integer literal, so that the actual base is 2, 8,
>   10, or 16.

Answer (score 22):

From the docs on `int`:

```
int(x=0) -> int or long
int(x, base=10) -> int or long
```

If x is **not a number** or if base is given, then x must be a string or Unicode object representing an integer literal in the given base.

So, `'0.0'` is an invalid integer literal for base 10.

You need:

```
>>> int(float('0.0'))
0
```

help on `int`:

```
>>> print int.__doc__
int(x=0) -> int or long
int(x, base=10) -> int or long

Convert a number or string to an integer, or return 0 if no arguments
are given.  If x is floating point, the conversion truncates towards zero.
If x is outside the integer range, the function returns a long instead.

If x is not a number or if base is given, then x must be a string or
Unicode object representing an integer literal in the given base.  The
literal can be preceded by '+' or '-' and be surrounded by whitespace.
The base defaults to 10.  Valid bases are 0 and 2-36.  Base 0 means to
interpret the base from the string as an integer literal.
>>> int('0b100', base=0)
4
```

Answer (score 5):

What you are trying to do is convert a string literal to an int. `'0.0'` can't be parsed to an integer because it contains a decimal point and therefore is unparseable as an integer.

However, if you use

```
int(0.0)
```

or

```
int(float('0.0'))
```

it will correctly parse.

Answer (score 3):

If you must, you might use

```
int(float('0.0'))
```

Answer (score 1):

you will need to convert the int to a float using this code:
*test = 0 testrun = float(int(test)) print(testrun)*
output: testrun = 0.0

Comment: I do not know how to use the text to code converter on this sorry!

Comment: Sorry to make your script run you will have to flip the code. just use int(float(0.0)) this will round the float to the nearest one. output 0

Comment: please note an int is a whole real number 0, 1, 2, 3 etc.. floats are numbers with a decimal 0.0, 1.0, 2.0 etc.. if we want to use a float in the position of an int we will need to convert the flot to and int vise versa