# Gives an error ' when inserting text in to a txt file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have two txt files. This files are created automatically and it also inserts '10' as a text into these files. But if the program reads the files it gives an error like "ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''". How can i fix this error?

```
    income_txta = open(("monthly_income,expences_amount\\income\\" + year + month + ".txt"), "a")
    income_txtr = open(("monthly_income,expences_amount\\income\\" + year + month + ".txt"), "r")
    if income_txtr.read() == '':
        income_txta.write("10")
        total_income=10
    else:
        total_income = int(income_txtr.read())

    expences_txta = open(("monthly_income,expences_amount\\expences\\" + year + month + ".txt"), "a")
    expences_txtr = open(("monthly_income,expences_amount\\expences\\" + year + month + ".txt"), "r")
    if expences_txtr.read() == '':
        expences_txta.write("10")
        total_expences = 10
    else:
        total_expences = int(expences_txtr.read())
        print(total_expences)
```

Comment: Possibly related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17142088/python-2-7-and-3-3-2-why-int0-0-does-not-work)

Comment: It tells you what's wrong (`ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''`), you're probably trying to convert an empty string to an integer with `int("")`.

Comment: That error is thrown because you are trying to convert empty string to int. And that's because you are appending 10 to the file object `income_txta`. What you should really is read the file content into memory not work on the file object.

Comment: Yes I thought that too. And i even checked these files manually. But actually they are not empty.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1841565/valueerror-invalid-literal-for-int-with-base-10)

Comment: No it doesn't answer my question I tried that too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the code like this and it worked.

```
    if os.path.exists("monthly_income,expences_amount\\income\\" + year + month + ".txt"):
        print("total_income_file exists")
    else:
        fh = open("monthly_income,expences_amount\\income\\" + year + month + ".txt", "w")

    if os.path.exists("monthly_income,expences_amount\\expences\\" + year + month + 
         ".txt"):
        print("total_expences_file exists")
    else:
                income_txtr = open(("monthly_income,expences_amount\\income\\" + year + month + ".txt"), "r")
    if income_txtr.read() == '':
        income_txta = open(("monthly_income,expences_amount\\income\\" + year + month + ".txt"), "a")
        income_txta.write("10")
        total_income=10
    else:
        income_txtr = open(("monthly_income,expences_amount\\income\\" + year + month + ".txt"), "r")
        total_income = int(income_txtr.read())


    expences_txtr = open(("monthly_income,expences_amount\\expences\\" + year + month + ".txt"), "r")
    if expences_txtr.read() == '':
        expences_txta = open(("monthly_income,expences_amount\\expences\\" + year + month + ".txt"), "a")
        expences_txta.write("10")
        total_expences = 10
    else:
        expences_txtr = open(("monthly_income,expences_amount\\expences\\" + year + month + ".txt"), "r")
        total_expences = int(expences_txtr.read())
        print(total_expences)fh = open("monthly_income,expences_amount\\expences\\" + year + month + ".txt", 
          "w")
```