# read matrix from file as int

Tags: python, arrays, file, matrix

I have a text file which contains matrix with distance between two points. I want to create a function that reads the matrix but witout ' '

my matrix looks like:

```
0.0 64.8 87.3 82.9 46.3 53.8
64.8 0.0 52.8 95.8 46.6 61.3
87.3 52.8 0.0 62.4 42.2 44.3
82.9 95.8 62.4 0.0 51.4 36.1
46.3 46.6 42.2 51.4 0.0 15.3
53.8 61.3 44.3 36.1 15.3 0.0
```

my code looks like:

```
def read_matrix(filename):
    matrix = []
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        matrix = [line.split() for line in f]
        return(matrix)
```

but but in this case it receives output as string date:

```
[['0.0', '64.8', '87.3', '82.9', '46.3', '53.8'], ['64.8', '0.0', '52.8', '95.8', '46.6', '61.3'], ['87.3', '52.8', '0.0', '62.4', '42.2', '44.3'], ['82.9', '95.8', '62.4', '0.0', '51.4', '36.1'], ['46.3', '46.6', '42.2', '51.4', '0.0', '15.3'], ['53.8', '61.3', '44.3', '36.1', '15.3', '0.0']]
```

so by reading other similar questions I try to create a function that reads date without ' ' --> like this [0.0, 64.8, 87.3, 82.9, 46.3, 53.8]

```
def read_matrix(filename):
    matrix = []
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        line = f.readline()
        words = line.split()
        for word in words:
            matrix.append(int(word))
    return(matrix)
```

but in every attempt I get fast the same error like:

```
invalid literal for int() with base 10: '0.0 64.8 87.3 82.9 46.3 53.8\n'
```

I also try this one:

```
def read_matrix(filename):
    matrix = []
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        matrix = [[int(num) for num in line.split(',')] for line in f if line.strip() != "" ]
        return(matrix)
```

but its also not working

Comment: "by reading other similar questions I try to create a function that reads date as integer" In your own words, what is an integer? When you receive a string like `"64.8"`, what do you want to get as a result? What is the name of that kind of thing?

Comment: i want output without "" also like 64.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the numbers you have are not int. Just replace 'int' with 'float' and it works

```
def read_matrix(filename):
    matrix = []
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
             matrix.append([float(word) for word in line.split()])
    return(matrix)
```

Comment: it almost works! but now as output its come only the first line of matrix

Comment: Yea you need to loop over the lines too, updated my answer

Comment: right! now the program reads the information correctly. thanks for finding my mistake and improving my code! :)

Comment: I would appreciate it if you accepted the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Your matrix contains floating point numbers (decimal s) so instead of `int()` function use `float()` function

Comment: the question is to int not to float

Comment: How can you say a decimal is an int

Answer (score 0):

```
matrix = []
with open("a.txt", 'r') as f:
    line = f.readline()
    words = line.split()
    for word in words:
        matrix.append(int(eval(word))
```

Here in your file 0.0 is there which is not a valid integer with base 10.
Please Visit this link for more information.
[Python 2.7 and 3.3.2, why int('0.0') does not work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17142088/python-2-7-and-3-3-2-why-int0-0-does-not-work)